# Position absolute vs min-height

Tags: css, position, height

I have a problem with position settings.. I have the scrolling type of page and every frame (like every section) is set to 100% width and height. They all have `position: absolute`. First frame top: 0, left: 0, second top: 100%, left: 0; etc...
But when I need more text, than it's possible on 100% height, I obviously can't display it, because of next section...
How can I set that positions correctly to this issue?

CSS:

```
#about {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background:white; 
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="about" class="yourDivClass">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a workable example in the question?

Comment: @JohnBupit: Well I don't have any working model webpage... But I hope I've explained it enough..

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll: I've tried to change "height" to "min-height" and add "clear" div after sections. But it didn't work..

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript/jQuery to dynamically set the top of each div when the document loads. Do not set any initial values for height in your CSS and let it extend to the full size it should take up.

HTML:

```
<div class='yourDivClass' id="div1">
     ...
</div>
<div class='yourDivClass' id="div2">
     ...
</div>
<div class='yourDivClass' id="div3">
     ...
</div>
<div class='yourDivClass' id="div4">
     ...
</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalHeight = 0;
    $(".yourDivClass").each(function() {
        $(this).css("top", totalHeight);
        var height = ($(this).height() > $(window).height()) ? $(this).height() : $(window).height();
        $(this).css("height", height);
        totalHeight += height;
    });
});
```

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gznox2f9/).

Comment: Thanks, but is it going to work like when there is not enough text for at least 100% height, it will still have that 100% height? If you know what I am trying to say..:)

Comment: @HynekŠ. Try that. Conditionals to ensure you take the greater between the window height and div height. Also, please note that with as system like this you'll need to handle window resizing

Comment: Ok, but I am really not good at jQuery, should I just paste it to the head of file? but there is "yourDivClass" field to edit, I have to set 5 div's, so shouldn't it be in every one of them? Sorry for that silly asking, but as I said, I am trying to start with jQuery...

Comment: @HynekŠ. This only works if each of the divs you are trying to edit have the same class. I'll add html to demonstrate

Comment: Thank you very much! I will let you know if it worked :)

Comment: Well it didn't work for me, but it's definitely my fault.. Should I keep position absolute and "top" and "left" settings? Probably not, right..:) I've just removed "height: 100%" settings

Comment: @HynekŠ. Post your code in your question and I can help you more

Comment: here it is. I've posted css code without any removes. HTML code is the same as your.

Comment: @HynekŠ. I need to see your html and css. I have no idea what the `about` id refers to.

Comment: OK, edited, sorry. And there are more divs like this one. The only difference is "top" settings. (like top: 200%, top: 300%, etc... )

Comment: @HynekŠ. Try that. Edited to reflect your code. See the attached jsFiddle for an example

Comment: Now it works that height is exactly for text included. But i need height to set min to 100%, because of some backgrounds etc... Is it possible to edit that jQuery to set min-height: 100%?

Comment: @HynekŠ. Just set min-height in your CSS. But that should not matter since the javascript is automatically handling setting the height for you. The min height is already defined.

Comment: Yeah! Now it works perfectly! Thank you so much for your time and patience!